# url passing parameters in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-routing

In zendframework ,When i am moving to new page with parameters using code as

`$this->_helper->redirector('my-action','my-controller',null,$params-array);` ,

it showing parameters in every url in application. Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What, exactly, is the issue you're trying to address?

Comment: I have one action function like this

Comment: I have one action function like this - function firstAction{ $this->_helper->redirector('second-action','my-controller',null,$params-array('val1'=>10)); } in browsing its works as http://website/mycontroller/second-action/val1/10 but problem arises when i browsing some other url of application  http://website/mycontroller/third -action/val1/10 but it should be http://website/mycontroller/third -action as i am not sending any parameter to this url.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
$params = array('user' => $user, 'mail' => $mail);
$this->_helper->redirector($action, $controller, $module, $params);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$this->_redirect('Controllername/action?para1=value&para2=value');
```

Try this it'work

I hope it helps you....

Comment: thanks to all , problem is solve out when i use  this 

$this->_redirect('Controllername/action?para1=value&para2=value');, thanks Mr Jalpesh Patel and also to all

Answer (score 0):

The url() view helper is provided by Zend Framework 2 and is used to create the links we need. The first parameter to url() is the route name we wish to use for construction of the URL, and the second parameter is an array of all the variables to fit into the placeholders to use. In this case we use our ‘album’ route which is set up to accept two placeholder variables: action and id.