# 404 after redirection

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have this redirection:

```
$this->_helper->redirector('freenights/supplierId/' . $sws. '/contractId/' . $con);
```

It redirects me to this url:

```
http://contract.local/contracts/freenights%2FsupplierId%2F3%2FcontractId%2F2
```

but I get this 404 error:

> The requested URL /contracts/freenights/supplierId/3/contractId/2 was
>   not found on this server.

If I don't have any problem going directly to

```
http://contract.local/contracts/freenights/supplierId/3/contractId/2
```

why am I getting the 404?

Comment: have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11554273/430112)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `goToUrl` method of `Redirector` helper. See [example 6 in Zend Framework manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.redirector.basicusage)

```
$this->_redirector = $this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector');
$this->_redirector->gotoUrl('freenights/supplierId/' . $sws. '/contractId/' . $con);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are getting 404 error due to URLEncoder issue, for test try with Header function.